# Add ffmpeg gpl to yocto

Tags: ffmpeg, yocto

Is it possible to compile a GPL/LGPL version of ffmpeg and add it to a yocto image? I always get a message about `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST`, but I do not want to enable the **commercial** licenses. In the recipe there is this line:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[gpl] = "--enable-gpl,--disable-gpl"
```

Is it meant to enable gpl build of ffmpeg?

Comment: The flag in question enables some components that are GPL (most of the code is LGPL). Your license error message refers to something else, it's hard to guess what exactly from the details provided.

Comment: The recipe does set the commercial flag for some reason. I think not because of specific license issues (ffmpeg should not have non-free code: do read their LICENSE.md file for some corner cases though) but because of potential patent issues -- This is only my personal speculation unfortunately.